# jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap : How to detect menu button is presses

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've tried the PhoneGap code at but it doesnt work. The click on menubutton on my Android device doesn't fire anything. 
I've seen people using native android menu handler, but I want a JavaScript one
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#menubutton
Can someone help me? Please?

Comment: Need more details. The menubutton event works fine on my devices and emulator.

Comment: I have the phonegap.js generated by dreamweaver, and i added this into my code :
<!-- html -->
function onLoad() {  
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
    }

    // Handle the menu button
    //
    function onMenuKeyDown() {
  alert("Android Menu Button !!!");
    }
<body onload="onLoad()">
The alert does not display! Any Idea?

Comment: sorry don't know how to format ...

Comment: I don't know much about the Dreamweaver integration but I'd put an alert in the onDeviceReady method to make sure it has been called. If you don't get a "deviceready" event you can't use PhoneGap commands.

Comment: I have the same error... But I get an error in my log https://gist.github.com/068cb455986c42272368. Jeelig do you have any log information?

Comment: sorry, does your menubutton event work?!!!

Comment: If you're using dreamweaver, notice that the phonegap version is too old to use this event. You will need to upgrade to a more recent version (menubutton is available since phonegap 0.9.6). Let me know if you want to know how to upgrade it. Otherwise Simon is right, you have to wait the device ready event to know if phonegap is running, so your code should be triggered only once the javascript phonegap file is loaded. Hope this will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon is right wait for the deviceready event to be sure phonegap is running